# nodejs - http/https request assíncrono

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tentando montar um módulo contendo uma função de http/https request baseado na URL informada, porém no módulo principal eu não obtenho nenhuma saída.

get.js

```
const https = require('https')
const http = require('http')

async function makeRequest(url) {
    var agent = (url.includes("https")) ? https : http
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var body = ''
        const req = agent
        .get(url,  (res) => {
            res.on('data', (data) => {  
                body += data
            });
        })
        resolve(body)
    })
}

module.exports.makeRequest = makeRequest
```

index.js

```
const get = require('./get')

async function pegarDados() {
    var resp = await get.makeRequest('http://brasil.io/api/dataset/covid19/caso/data/?city=Ribeir%C3%A3o+Preto&format=json&is_last=True&state=SP')
    console.log(resp)
}

pegarDados()
```

A esquematização está correta?

Comment: @RafaelTavares então, sem usar async eu até consegui... mas desse jeito que estou tentando não quer ir.. queria entender o motivo...

Comment: A resposta da outra pergunta utiliza `http.request()`, não `http.get()`

Comment: Consegui usando o método request ao inves do get.